# stuck on writing this query, trying to use inner join

Tags: sql, database, select, inner-join

My database:

```
EMPLOYEE (fmane, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno)     KEY: ssn
DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)               KEY: dnumber.
PROJECT  (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum)                          KEY: pnumber.
WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours)                                         KEY: (essn, pno)
DEPENDENT  (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship)             KEY: (essn, dependent-name)
```

I want get the last name of married employees who have no children using inner join

So far I can only come up with this:

```
SELECT E.*
FROM Employee AS E INNER JOIN Dependent AS D
ON ( E.ssn = D.essn AND D.relationship IN ( 'husband','wife') )
```

Anyway want to give to correct my code? I want to use inner join to find what I want.

Comment: Thanks for putting in what have you tried so far, but it would really help to know some sample data in tables/your expected output and the database name/version

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Another way without using minus

```
select e.lname from
employee e inner join dependent d
on e.ssn=d.essn 
where D.relationship IN ('husband','wife')
and e.ssn not in (
    select e.ssn from
    employee e inner join dependent d
    on e.ssn=d.essn 
    where D.relationship IN ('child')
)
```

With Minus

```
SELECT e.lname
FROM Employee E 
INNER JOIN Dependent D
ON E.ssn = D.essn 
where D.relationship IN ('husband','wife')

minus

select e.lname
FROM Employee E 
INNER JOIN Dependent D
ON E.ssn = D.essn 
where D.relationship IN ('child') --or children what ever you are using
```

Comment: Yep. I see it now. Correcting.

Comment: `minus` is non-standard SQL. The ANSI SQL equivalent is `except`

Comment: Thanks! Tried another approach using `not in`

Comment: can I ask on e.ssn=d.essn, is that join dependent with empolyee, is that to find the birthday?

Comment: It is just to join employee and dependent based on common key. If you want to display `birthdate` or any other column from `employee` table, you can use them in outer select query. Or use `e.*` in outer select to get all the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  The inner query finds all employees who have only one dependent, which could be a spouse *or* another family member.  I then join this result again to the `Dependent` table and restrict that other family member to be a husband or wife.

```
SELECT e1.*
FROM Employee e1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT e2.ssn
    FROM Employee e2 INNER JOIN Dependent d1 ON e2.ssn = d1.essn
    GROUP BY e2.ssn
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t ON e1.ssn = t.ssn
INNER JOIN Dependent d2 ON e1.ssn = d2.essn
WHERE d2.relationship IN ('husband', 'wife')
```